# How do I fix this wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

Thank you for any help. I am trying to fix the sidebar on this page
http://outfoxedmedia.com/skincare/winners-circle/

I believe the problem might be in the sidebar loop is not correct. There are 3 text widgets being used in the sidebar with just images and they are not lining up correctly or stacked on top of each other. What is wrong here and how can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the html your sidebar loop outputs seems to be off. More precisely, it outputs this:

```
<ul class="sidebar_list">
  <li class="widget widget_text">           
    <div class="textwidget">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://outfoxedmedia.com/skincare/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/sidebar1.png" border="0" alt="" width="252" height="252" /></a>
    </div>
  </div> //<-- Sup
  </li>
```

There's an extra closing div tag for each list item.

Comment: Thank you for the help. So I will have to fix the loop inside the sidebar.php file? Is the extra div being output by this loop?Please see the sidebar code below. I'm stumped here.

Comment: `<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the primary and secondary widget areas.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers HTML5 3.0
 */
?>

 <div id="sidebar_1" class="sidebar">
         <ul class="sidebar_list">

         <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-widget-area' ) ) : ?>         

          <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>

  </ul>
 </div>`

Comment: Look for (perhaps in your functions.php) how your 'sidebar-widget-area' is registered with a function register_sidebar() or register_sidebars(). My guess is you have defined `'before_widget' => '<li ...>'` and `'after_widget' => '</div></li>'` or something along those lines. You need to match those. [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) lists all the options that can be used when registering sidebars.